# zend framework update with swap value expression

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I try to make universal update / swap which would always switch active status. In SQL is simple:

```
UPDATE contacts SET active = ABS( active - 1 ) WHERE id = ....
```

Where active is small int / flag 0 or 1, so it always work.

When I try to implement it to model class extend Zend_Db_Table:

```
public function disableContact( $contact_id )
{
    $where = $this->getAdapter( )->quoteInto( 'id = ?', $contact_id );
    $data = Array( );
    $data ['active'] = '(ABS( the.contacts.active - 1 ))';

    return parent::update( $data, $where );
}
```

I got `Error: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "(ABS( the.contacts.active - 1 ))"<p><pre>#0 ......./ZendFramework-1.11.0/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)`

How to pass ABS expression to update ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Zend_Db_Expr`, eg

```
// Updated with zerkms' much simpler bit flipping logic
$data['active'] = new Zend_Db_Expr('1 - the.contacts.active');
```

The best example I can find in the manual is for inserting data but the concept is the same. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.insert

FYI Only `Zend_Db_Select` recognises values wrapped in parentheses and treats them as expressions.

Comment: +1. And `ABS` is unnecessary here: `1 - the.contacts.active` will return what you need

Comment: Zend_Db_Expr works perfectly - thank you. `1-active` is a great idea too - thank you